# Show Popup only if content is present

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Content for my popup is dynamically generated. If only the content is present I have to show the popup/popover. Moreover this popover needs to be called after an API call is made.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/

```
<div ng-app="customDirectives">
    <div> <span custom-popover popover-html="Some Popover Text" popover-placement="bottom" popover-label="Label"></span>

    </div>
</div>


customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
customDirectives.directive('customPopover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('CustomComponents', ['customDirectives']);
```

Comment: Your popover-html will be feed by a controller, right? Use ng-if on the span element with the html content.

Comment: [@JonathanAnctil] under the span I have many tags. adding ng-if to that will make the code repeat twice. Instead, I thought it would be better to add the condition to the directive

Comment: I'm not sure why your code have to be repeat twice with ng-if... if you check popoverHtml in the directive and don't bother initialize it if the string is empty (popover()) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call popover() only if content is available,

```
    if(attrs.popoverHtml){
      $(el).popover({
          trigger: 'click',
          html: true,
          content: attrs.popoverHtml,
          placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
      });
    }
```

As you mentioned dynamic text, have updated the fiddle to show popover based on the dynamic text
http://jsfiddle.net/Vinthi/hthq965t/2/